# Is that normal Unit testing takes all the behavior out of my classes?

Tags: unit-testing, oop, design-patterns

I'm starting a new project and I want to use unit testing.

So I wrote my services classes which are implementing interface and waiting for interface in their parameters so I can easily mock these classes.

My question: there is absolutely no code in my business class! (like Customer)

Is it normal? is it normal even without unit test ? what kind of code would you put in a class like "Customer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't sound normal to me - unless you are at the very beginning of your project and `Customer` is as yet just a skeleton, and you *know* it will get more functionality over time.

Otherwise it may be a sign of a *design* issue, such as an [*anemic domain model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model).

It is not the unit tests' fault. Unit tests don't in any way enforce one to create dumb classes without real functionality.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is , I can't see anything that I should put in my customer class ! For instance a Customer can attend to a course (fitness business) so I'll create a CourseAttendanceService class so I can add / remove a link between a course and a customer but I won't do "myCustomer.Attend(aCourse)".

Comment: @remi, if it is not the customer's responsibility to attend a course, then whose?

Comment: @Péter I agree with you but if we start here, in a customer oriented application everything is the responsibility of the customer so we break the Single Responsibility Principle. And also if I put the method Attend in the customer class, I'll have to had a dependency with my datalayer ? And I am in a web environment so the datalayer s maybe the only layer that matters.

Comment: @remi, it depends on the level of abstraction. SRP does not mean that you should have a separate class for every activity a customer might engage in - that is taking it to the extreme, where it does more harm than good. A Customer should represent a real world customer, with all its responsibilities and actions relevant to this domain, period. However, the *details* of a specific complicated task can indeed be delegated to other classes. Dependency on the data layer is not a Bad Thing per se, as long as it is represented by (and hidden behind) a mockable interface.

Comment: @Péter : ok, so how should I send the implementation to the customer class ? In it's constructor ? In the method call ? or directly in the method by calling my framework (ninject here) ?

Comment: @remi, but if you want to avoid the dependency to the data layer, you can still do it the way ORM frameworks do, i.e. doing only the save/load part in the data layer, while allowing all the rest of the business logic to still reside in the application domain classes.

Comment: @remi, either one of these can be OK, depending on the circumstances. If you are going to use the service multiple times, it is best to inject it in the constructor.

Comment: @Péter : I think I got what you mean : the responsibility of an object is to change its state (ie the Customer will add an element to it's field "Courses") and the ORM will put these changes in the database. So I'll have to create a service class that call the "AddCourse" method and save the change with the ORM (doing it in the controller seems bad).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if *normal* is the right word here, I'd rather say that the situation you have found yourself in is very common.

I see this happen most often with people starting in on Domain Driven Design and also when people use design patterns such as MVVM - all the logic falls into services and controllers and managers (which are themself a smell IMO), and the core domain model becomes a very anaemic set of DTOs.

What I would suggest is returning to your object modelling and looking at your services and seeing where you have removed logic from your `Customer` object which is actually a core concern of the customer. That is - what does the customer object do? Some of this will belong in external services, but there will also be key processes which are the domain of the customer.

Comment: As I said, here it's a web app so I think that most of the work is about the datalayer so I don't want to have a link between my datalayer and my customer class.

Answer (score 1):

When you design clearly, there might be the case, where some classes are just aggregates of Data. This is part of the MVC Pattern, where the models should not contain much logic. However if you do have absolutely no code in your classes there is something seriously wrong.

To me it sounds, like you are trying some kind of dependency injection, but you are not only injecting the dependencies, but rather everything. This is taking the pattern to far, so it might be becoming it's own anti-pattern.